# Merge/join lists of dictionaries based on a common value in Python

Tags: python, django

I have two lists of dictionaries (returned as Django querysets). Each dictionary has an ID value. I'd like to merge the two into a single list of dictionaries, based on the ID value.

For example:

```
list_a = [{'user__name': u'Joe', 'user__id': 1},
          {'user__name': u'Bob', 'user__id': 3}]
list_b = [{'hours_worked': 25, 'user__id': 3},
          {'hours_worked': 40, 'user__id': 1}]
```

and I want a function to yield:

```
list_c = [{'user__name': u'Joe', 'user__id': 1, 'hours_worked': 40},
          {'user__name': u'Bob', 'user__id': 3, 'hours_worked': 25}]
```

Additional points to note:

- The IDs in the lists may not be in the same order (as with the example above).
- The lists will *probably* have the same number of elements, but I want to account for the option if they're not but keeping all the values from list_a (essentially `list_a OUTER JOIN list_b USING user__id`).
- I've tried doing this in SQL but it's not possible since some of the values are aggregates based on some exclusions.
- It's safe to assume there will only be at most one dictionary with the same `user__id` in each list due to the database queries used.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure those are tuples? The `{}` syntax is for dictionaries...

Comment: These are not tuples, and why don't you show us the code you have right now?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question and replaced tuples with dictionaries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.groupby` to group the elements:

```
lst = sorted(itertools.chain(list_a,list_b), key=lambda x:x['user__id'])
list_c = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x:x['user__id']):
    d = {}
    for dct in v:
        d.update(dct)
    list_c.append(d)
    #could also do:
    #list_c.append( dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dct.items() for dct in v)) )
    #although that might be a little harder to read.
```

If you have an aversion to `lambda` functions, you can always use `operator.itemgetter('user__id')` instead.  (it's probably slightly more efficient too)

To demystify lambda/itemgetter a little bit, Note that:

```
def foo(x):
    return x['user__id']
```

is the same thing* as either of the following:

```
foo = operator.itemgetter('user__id')
foo = lambda x: x['user__id']
```

*There are a few differences, but they're not important for this problem

Comment: [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) might be a good call here.

Comment: one-liner `[dict(y for x in g for y in x.items()) for k,g in groupby(lis,key=lambda x:x['user__id'])]`

Comment: Great solution, but worth noting that this will trample all but the last value in the result set for the same `user_id` if there are multiple rows for that `user_id` that contain the same value key.  Probably fine for this question, but could be a tricky problem if it is a concern.

Comment: @sr2222 -- You're right, it will do that, but if that is a concern, then this isn't a well-posed problem (OP never said how that should be handled)  :)

Comment: Well, the specs he provides don't explicitly state that such a condition can't occur, but given the type of data he appears to be working with, it's probably a safe assumption that there's no duplicates.

Comment: @sr2222 -- Sure he doesn't specify that it can't occur (maybe it can).  But he doesn't specify *how* it should be handled should the case arise.  And that's not something that I think we could reasonably guess (as far as I can see it, keeping the last one is just as good of a way to handle it as anything else).

Comment: Wow, impressed by the number and speed of responses here. Very much appreciated. I've tried the code originally suggested by @mgilson and it works a charm. Now to do a bit more reading to fully understand how it works :)

Comment: @sr2222 Good shout. Thankfully for this situation there won't be any duplicate `user__id` value keys due to the db query used.

Comment: Sorting, grouping, and itemgetter all seem like unnecessary overhead for some dicts.

Comment: @Marcin -- Maybe.  `grouping` really doesn't introduce any more overhead than your simple for loop.  `itemgetter` doesn't introduce much more overhead than is already present in `__getitem__`, so `sorting` is the only stage which is really "unnecessary" here.  However, if OP wants to have a list at the end of the day, it's possible that having a sorted list is desirable in which case OP would need to sort your output as well.  (that said, your output would be smaller, so it would be a faster sort).  Anyway, yours is a nice answer.  +1 to it.

Comment: @mgilson Quite. It's not just computational overhead, but also simple code length and readability.

Answer (score 6):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

list_a = [{'user__name': u'Joe', 'user__id': 1},
      {'user__name': u'Bob', 'user__id': 3}]
list_b = [{'hours_worked': 25, 'user__id': 3},
      {'hours_worked': 40, 'user__id': 1}]

collector = defaultdict(dict)

for collectible in chain(list_a, list_b):
    collector[collectible['user__id']].update(collectible.iteritems())

list_c = list(collector.itervalues())
```

As you can see, this just uses another dict to merge the existing dicts. The trick with defaultdict is that it takes out the drudgery of creating a dict for a new entry.

There is no need to group or sort these inputs. The dict takes care of all of that.

A truly bulletproof solution would catch the potential key error in case the input does not have a 'user__id' key, or use a default value to collect up all of the dicts without such a key.